# Angular 4 deep copy for nested object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, deep-copy

Here is my code

```
var destObj= Object.assign({}, sourceObj);
    destObj.fields.forEach(item => {
        if (item.fieldType == 'MULTI_SELECT_LOV') {
            let newValues = [];
            item.selectedValue.forEach(val => {
                newValues.push(val.dataName);
            });
            item.selectedValue = newValues;
        }
    })
```

after completion of code execution the both 'sourceObj' and 'destObj' are equal.

My intention is do not effect changes which are made on 'destObj' should not reflect in 'sourceObj'.

Comment: better use a library `loadash`

Comment: in my experience, the best way to deep copy is to serialize and deserialize to object